# trying to compile chromium-browser from source, but failing with 'map' file not found

Tags: 18.04, development, clang

I have downloaded source for chromium-browser.
Also:

```
 apt-get source chromium-browser
 sudo apt install build-essential
 sudo apt-get build-dep chromium-browser
```

I have installed libraries (and more):

```
sudo apt install cmake ninja-build clang-6.0 libglu1-mesa-dev libc++-dev libc++abi-dev libxi-dev


dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b
```

fails with:

```
fatal error: 'memory' file not found
...
fatal error: 'iosfwd' file not found
...
fatal error: 'vector' file not found
...

fatal error: 'map' file not found
#include <map>
         ^~~~~
1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/gn/bootstrap/bootstrap.py", line 96, in <module>
```

this is just a standard library file, what is going wrong?

full build output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/54v5CwW3qD/

clang++ -v test.cpp 
showed me that it seemed to be looking for v8 of libstdc++-8-dev 
Answer: I installed package g++-8 and libstdc++-8-dev

Then it built successfully.

Comment: Please provide the complete build output. If it's too long, use https://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: build output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/54v5CwW3qD/

Comment: It seems you're building a source package from a PPA. A build from the Ubuntu repos' source package worked fine for me: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BT22fQ9rpt/

Comment: yes, you're correct. It has only one patch I think, so I didn't think it would matter. I will contact the maintainer in that case.

Comment: Your output also mentioned some missing variables (`GOOGLEAPI_APIKEY_UBUNTU`, etc.). Not sure if those are relevant though (my output didn't include any such message).

Comment: my problem is actually much more fundamental. A simple c++ file with<iostream> fails to compile: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/G5pXCyYCx6/

yet the same compiles with g++: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3YgKT5Gp5b/

Comment: I installed g++ v8 from Synaptic, which added the v8 libstdc++  and now the compile is running, but I don't know why clang++ was looking for this version of libstdc++